# Passing an event handler as argument in C#

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writing down a customized Timer, that extends DispatcherTimer. It has a method called TimerSetUp, in which I associate the Tick event to an EventHandler.

```
public class MyTimer : DispatcherTimer
{
     public MyTimer(){}
     public void TimerSetUp(EventHandler<EventArgs> _EventHandler)
     {
         base.Tick += _EventHandler;
     }
}
```

I have now another couple of classes, StopwatchTimer and CountdownTimer, that extend MyTimer. Let's look at CountdownTimer.

```
public class CountdownTimer : MyTimer
{
     public CountdownTimer()
     {
         base.TimerSetUp(CountdownTimer_Tick);
     }

     public void CountdownTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         //...do something
     }
}
```

When either of them is declared, the constructor must call the **base class method** TimerSetUp and just set up the event handler.

The problem is that, in the signature of the TimerSetUp function, it gives me this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler<System.EventArgs>'
to'System.EventHandler<object>
```

And I can't get rid of it. If I just put TimerSetUp inside CountdownTimer, and just assign directly the event handler, like this

```
base.Tick += CountdownTimer_Tick;
```

it works, but I'd really like to make it work the other way.
So I'd like to know if

*1) There's a way I can resolve this*

*2) Is this a good approach to extensibility of the code?*

Comment: EventHandler without EventArgs

Comment: @Steve it gives the same error

Comment: Weird, I used your code and just removed the `<EventArgs>` (not needed with the standard EventHandler delegate) The `<TEventArgs>` is required if you supply your own EventArgs derived instance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You are mixing up the WPF and the UWP definition of DispatcherTimer.  They have a different definition of the Tick event, UWP wants the second argument of the event handler to be *object* instead of *EventArgs*.  So TimerSetUp() is declared wrong.  Consider writing your event handlers the UWP-way or encapsulating the DispatcherTimer instead of inheriting it.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, it figures. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I made it. I just casted a generic object in the function signature and wrapped a new eventHandler inside the code.

```
public void TimerSetUp(EventHandler<object> _EventHandler)
{
   base.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(_EventHandler);
}
```

Comment: If `_EventHandler` is of `EventHandler<object>` type already, why do you need to wrap it?

Comment: Yeah, that crossed my mind too. I guess Visual Studio is kinda bothered about this.

Answer (score 0):

DispatchTimer.Tick seems to be the non generic `EventHandler` rather than `EventHandler<EventArgs>`. Since you are using the base `EventArgs` anyway, they are functionally equivalent:

```
public void TimerSetUp(EventHandler _EventHandler)
 {
     base.Tick += _EventHandler;
 }
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Still doesn't work. Look at this screenshot I just made. 
[link](http://prntscr.com/c2mitd)